# Miltiple rows update with sql

Tags: php, sql, insert

by one queryWell, i got two php functions. Both of them should insert some values into DB tables. So the first one

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (thumb) VALUES ('$path')");`

doing thins in cycle.
But then i nedd to add some values in other column but the problem is that all of thouse values stores in array. That how function was look like.

```
 function uploading_paths($names_array){
    $data = '(\'' . implode('\'),(\'', $names_array) . '\')';
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `images` (`image_path`) VALUES $data");

}
```

So how can I add values from $data array in rows with already filled `thumb` columns by one query?
Is it possible?

Comment: i want to update. it was insert before cuz when i writed it i thought there gonna bv only one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using PHP PDO for this. It lets you prepare a statement and then execute it as many times as you want. Example:

```
$mysql_host = "127.0.0.1";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "myShop";
$dbLink = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$mysql_database;charset=utf8", $mysql_user, $mysql_password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
$dbLink->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
$query = $dbLink->prepare("insert into `images` (`thumb`, `path`) values (?, ?);");
foreach ($names_array as $thumb => $path)
{  
    $query->execute(array($thumb, $path)); // note the order as they should appear
}
```

Eventually you could replace the last path by:

```
$query = $dbLink->prepare("insert into `images` (`thumb`, `path`) values (:thumb, :path);");
foreach ($names_array as $thumb => $path)
{  
    $query->execute(array(":path" => $path, ":thumb" => $thumb)); // no order restriction
}
```

... and you won`t have to supply the array of execute in the order you have the fields.

Regards !